# Javascript: Resetting variable value created by form

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

I've created a form whereby the user enters details which are stored in variables or calculated depending on user entry. When clicking the button, a message will be displayed showing a message with the cost variable. The form clears but the message remains. The problem I have is that the form will update the cost value but will not update the message to show the error message. I'm sure there is something simple I am missing?

*to understand what I mean, please test the fiddle by: adding dimensions 20 into each dimension box and zone 2 in the next box. click the button and the cost will display to £40. enter 20 again in each new box and this time enter 3 in zone. Cost updates to £60. However, try entering 6 or 7 in the zone box and the error message should show but it does not?

I think the var cost is storing the previous value and so the default switch will not trigger? How can I reset the cost var? (I have tried cost=null at the end but it does not work;keeps the same msg and reads £null).

http://jsfiddle.net/6dxLou41/

Sorry for the long code. Hope it makes sense.

html

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" name="data" id="length" maxlength="4"/>Length (cm)
<input type="text" name="data" id="width" maxlength="4"/>Width (cm)
<input type="text" name="data" id="height" maxlength="4"/>Height (cm)<br>           
<input type="text" name="data" id="zone" maxlength="4"/>Zone<br><br>
<button type="button" id="click_button">click</button>
</form>

<div id="message"></div>
```

CSS

```
#message {
visibility:hidden;
}

#message.show {
visibility:visible;  
}
```

JS

```
var cost;

var button=document.getElementById("click_button");
var msg=document.getElementById("message");

function load(){
button.addEventListener("click",getSize, false);
}

window.onload=load();

function getSize(){
var length=document.getElementById("length").value;
var width=document.getElementById("height").value;
var height=document.getElementById("height").value;
var zone=document.getElementById("zone").value;
    function checkSize(){
           if (length<50 && width<50 && height<50) {
               smallBox(zone);
               }
           else if (length>=50 && width>=50 && height>=50) {
               largeBox(zone);
               }
     }
checkSize();
}
           function smallBox(zone){
               switch(zone){
               case "1":
                   cost=20;
               break;
               case "2":
                   cost=40;
               break;
               case "3":
                   cost=60;
               break;
               default:
                   errorMsg();
               break;
               }
               if(!isNaN(cost)){
               showMsg();
               }
            }

           function largeBox(zone){
               switch(zone){
               case "1":
                   cost=40;
               break;
               case "2":
                   cost=60;
               break;
               case "3":
                   cost=80;
               break;
               default:
                   errorMsg();
               break;
               }
               showMsg();
            }

function errorMsg(){
msg.innerText="Error. Please check the details entered and try again"; 
msg.className="show";
resetForm();
}

function showMsg(){
msg.innerText="Thank you. The cost will be £" + cost;
msg.className="show";
resetForm();
}

function resetForm(){
document.getElementById("form").reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your

```
function resetForm(){
 document.getElementById("form").reset();
}
```

should be

```
function resetForm(){
 document.getElementById("form").reset();
 msg.innerText="";
 msg.className="";
}
```

basically: you are not re-setting #message back to hidden which is where you start. And, I am also making sure that innerText is blank.

Comment: I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dxLou41/7/). May be run and see if that what you need. I changed innerText to innerHTML (somehow I could not get innerText to work ...) and also added a setTimeout to check if the solution would work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that was not the problem. If you try your fiddle and enter 5 in the zone box (hopefully triggering the 'default' switch then an error message should appear but it doesn't. Further, the original issue remains. It I generate a message for the cost variable, and then try to generate the error message the cost message appears?

Comment: @user4612360 can you try this once again [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dxLou41/9/) ?

Comment: Thanks. I sorted it by reorganising the code into the same function and declaring the var cost inside the function, therefore resetting it on every click/ load. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
var cost;
```

to

```
var cost=0;
```

Comment: at the bottom of the switch I added a default, if the zone does not match any cases, then the error message is generated. Then I check if cost !isNaN (if it is the showMsg function is called). This works only after a complete reload of the page however?